# What is the name of the $\in$ symbol and where does it come from?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, math-history

It looks like a lower-case epsilon, but the Wikipedia page on epsilon states that they are not the same.

Does this symbol have a typographic identification outside of mathematics? Where did the symbol come from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the **membership relation**, but in set theory this is also known as **the epsilon relation**, and historically the notation was indeed $\varepsilon$.

(For example, I have the book from 1948 by Tarski and Jonsson *Cardinal Algebras* where such notation is employed.)

According to [this page](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) it was Peano who used epsilon. I suppose somewhere around the 1960's or so, when typography was easier to modify the symbol was taking the modern shape of $\in$ (Bourbaki in their set theory book, ca. 1970, were using $\in$).

Comment: The symbol was introduced by Peano in volume I of his *Formulaire de mathématiques* from 1901 (Prémiere partie, "Logique mathématique", page 1, Chapter 1, section 1, item 4: "$x\varepsilon a$ signifie '$x$ est un $a$'."). Available here: http://archive.org/details/formulairedesmat00pean

Comment: @Andres: Thanks! I still find some typographical distance from $\epsilon$ to $\in$, though.

Comment: I agree; Peano used $\varepsilon$ instead of $\epsilon$ or our $\in$. This identifies *when* it appeared. The next step is to trace how the symbol evolved.

Comment: Ah, yes. Although the link I provide in my answer points to an even earlier text...

Comment: I see; nice. The difference between $\varepsilon$ and $\epsilon$ seems stylistic, though, and probably different printers chose one or the other at whim on early years. Cajori's "A history of mathematical notation", volume 2, item 689, uses $\epsilon$ and credits Peano.

Comment: Peano's Arithmetices principia: nova methodo (1889) can be seen here: http://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog The symbol here is an $\epsilon$ close to our $\in$, actually. It is introduced in page x. "Signum $\in$ significat *est*. Ita $a\in b$ legitur $a$ *est quoddam* $b$", etc.

Comment: I read or was told early in my schooling that the epsilon was the first letter of the Greek word “is”: $\epsilon\sigma\tau\grave\iota$. The distinction between $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ is merely calligraphic.

Comment: Whitehead and Russell's *Principia Mathematica* used $\epsilon$.

Comment: I think that the different styles are due to typographical exigences. In Bertrand Russell's paper *Mathematical Logic as Based on the Theory of Types* (1908), it looks like the "original" one : $ε$, while in the first edition of *PM* (1910) it is clearly $ϵ$.