# First usage of the symbol ∈

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request, notation, math-history

Concerning a book [1] I am reading the symbol $\in$ was first used by [Giuseppe Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_peano) and is the first letter $\epsilon$ ([epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon)) of the word [ἐστί](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AF) (means "is"). Does anyone know in which work of Peano $\in$ was first used?

[1] Ingmar Lehmann, Wolfgang Schulz: "Mengen, Relationen, Funktionen" (3. Auflage, 2007), page 10

Similar question: [What is the name of the ∈ symbol and where does it come from?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299841/what-is-the-name-of-the-in-symbol-and-where-does-it-come-from)

Comment: This was asked at least once before. If your intention is to ask a question just for answering it yourself, perhaps it's best to see that it wasn't asked before.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I answered the question 30 min after I posted the question here on stackexchange (after luckily finding the linked Wikipedia article)... I really did not know the answer before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementzeichen#Geschichte it was first used 1889 in the work *Arithmetices principia nova methodo exposita* (page X):

> „Signum ϵ significat est. Ita a ϵ b legitur a est quoddam b“

This means something like (my translation which isn't the best!):

> The symbol ϵ means *is*. So a ϵ b has to be read as a *is a* b

Here is a link to the work: https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog

The quoted sentence in the [original work](https://ia600200.us.archive.org/3/items/arithmeticespri00peangoog/arithmeticespri00peangoog.pdf):

[image: reference]

Comment: Your translation is good. Note that it's not Latin, but *latino sine flexione* (that is, Latin without inflection), a “universal” language invented by Peano himself. I don't know when $\epsilon$ came to be realized as $\in$; Kelley still uses $\varepsilon$ in his “General Topology”.

Comment: @ereg: Thanks for your notes! Can you confirm the date 1889? The [Wikipedia article in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory#Sets.2C_membership_and_equality) says it was 1988...

Comment: @tampis Just a matter of when precisely the book was published, I would think. Maybe one edition or translation was published in 1888, and another in 1889.

Comment: I know 1889 as the date of first publication. But I can't exclude Peano used the symbol in some preceding paper.

Comment: A lot of modern notations have their first appearance in *principia nova*.

Comment: I think that the different styles are due to typographical exigences. In Bertrand Russell's paper *Mathematical Logic as Based on the Theory of Types* (1908), it looks like the "original" one : $ε$, while in the first edition of *PM* (1910) it is clearly $ϵ$.

Comment: @egreg It doesn't look like *latino sine flexione*.  Peano follows all the rules of Classical Latin grammar here, regarding both case (signo/signum, classis/classibus) and gender (quoddam/quaedam, nova methodo).  His proposal of *latino sine flexione* came more than ten years after this publication.