# Etymology of symbols $\in$ and $\varnothing$

Tags: terminology

I read many years ago in somewhere (I don't remember where) that the symbol $\in$ for membership of sets comes from Greek word "$\epsilon\sigma\tau\iota$" meaning "is in". So $a\in A$ means $a$ is in $A$.

It it right? If is so, then what about symbol of empty set "$\varnothing$" which looks like letter $\phi$?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://hsm.stackexchande.com/.

Comment: For $\in$, see the post [first-usage-of-the-symbol $\in$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762846/first-usage-of-the-symbol-%e2%88%88). Correct: the source is Peano (1889).

Comment: For $\emptyset$, see [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Set Theory and Logic: The null set symbol](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html): first appeared in N. Bourbaki, *Éléments de mathématique Fasc.1: Les structures fondamentales de l'analyse; Liv.1: Theorie de ensembles* (1939).

Comment: Empty set (nullset) looks rather like 0.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Right. Sorry about that. I should have checked.